# How to Apply not in condition inside the populate in mongoose with express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How to apply "not in" query inside populate as below in Mongoose with Express js ?

```
Users
  .find({ user_enabled: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'books',
    match: { 'language': 'en' },
```

> [ Not in en language ]

```
  })
  .exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) Comparison Query Operator for this

Example:

```
Users
  .find({ user_enabled: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'books',
    match: { 'language': 'en' }, 
    match: { "language": { "$nin": ['xx','yy'] } }  // <= See here
  })
  .exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Users
  .find({ user_enabled: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'books',
    match: { 'language': {$not: 'en'} }, })
  .exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$ne` operator?

So in your case:

```
Users
  .find({ user_enabled: true })
  .populate({
    path: 'books',
    match: { language: { $ne: "en" } },
})
.exec()
```